# getText() or textProperty.getValue() ? -> TextFields

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

Iam working on a Textfield for numbers. I need to copy the input from one textfield to the other.

What would the difference be between these two:
`FieldTwo.setText(FieldOne.getText());`
And
`FieldTwo.setText(FieldOne.textProperty().getValue());`

Comment: which gui framework? if both works, just take the easiest one.

Comment: JavaFX. I was wondering because I couldn't find the difference and thought that there may be something more to the .textProperty().getValue() one

Comment: according to the docs [1](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.TextProperty.html) [2](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html), value no difference. I think they both exist because they implement different interfaces, which would help support different design patterns.

Comment: you mean for awt and swing and so on?  this would makes sense...  thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: `textProperty` has other properties such as `.Name` and I think it is useful in some cases, this is at least one reason `.text` is not enough.

Comment: so could i think of it as a richer version of .getText?.  I understand that there would be other situations in which it could be used, but wanted to know if i was misunderstanding anything in the example above (only coping the date from one Textfield to another)

Comment: in your case i think you should use `FieldOne.getText()` directly.

Comment: would you please bother to write this as an answer so that i could choose it and close the question?

Comment: done. but another super one answered before me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<propertyName>Property()` accessors are used for binding and change or invalidation listeners. That way you can react to future changes to the property.

The `getValue()` accessor on the property allows you to get the property value at that time.

When a property is defined, you can just define the property() accessor and the client will have access to the full functionality of the property, including the ability to get and set the current property value.  However, it is by convention (and makes code easier to read) if additional getters and setters for the property value are defined on the object defining the property.

The `get<propertyName>()` method is just a shorthand for the current property value. It also allows a class with properties to conform to [Java bean naming conventions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javaserver-pages-3rd/0596005636/ch20s01s01.html).  This is useful in meeting developer expectations for class interfaces and aiding automated tooling, e.g. Jackson or jaxb object serialization or IDE code generation tasks.

Study the [property tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) for more tutorial on defining and using properties.

For your example, use the following if you want the value of fieldOne to be the current value of fieldTwo:

```
fieldTwo.setText(fieldOne.getText());
```

Use the following if you want the value of fieldOne to always be the value of fieldTwo, even when fieldTwo changes.

```
fieldTwo.textProperty().bind(fieldOne.textProperty());
```

Use the following if you want the value of fieldOne to always be the value of fieldTwo, even when fieldTwo changes and vice versa.

```
fieldTwo.textProperty().bindBidirectional(fieldOne.textProperty());
```

Note, when I did this, I followed another naming convention for the property reference, `fieldOne` instead of `FieldOne` as you have in your question.  Always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

So you can see that the different accessors are useful for different access patterns, which is why the library follows conventions to provide access to that functionality.  It is advisable that you follow similar conventions for any code you write that defines properties.

Properties in JavaFX can be more subtle than simple read write properties, though those are the most common.

Once you understand simple properties and wish to understand property functionality more fully, study the:

- [Property pattern cookbook](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/JavaFX+Property+Architecture)
- The target of the linked cookbook is advanced users.
- You do *not* need to understand everything in the linked article to
  make use of simple properties.

Answer (score 2):

In short: They return the same value. In your case you can simply pick the shorter one `.getText()`, becuase it types less code.

From the docs:
[TextProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.TextProperty.html)

> All Implemented Interfaces: Observable, Property<java.lang.String>,
> ReadOnlyProperty<java.lang.String>,
> ObservableObjectValue<java.lang.String>, ObservableStringValue,
> ObservableValue<java.lang.String>,
> WritableObjectValue<java.lang.String>, WritableStringValue,
> WritableValue<java.lang.String>

You can see `TextProperty` exists to support events listener(Observe pattern), bindings, which are useful especially when you're designing some frameworks. For example, in a typical UI designer, you select a `TextInputControl`, the property grid shows the name(`TextProperty.getName()`), the text, etc, and can update(binding) it in property grid.

I also checked [jfx source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx)
*modules\javafx.controls\src\main\java\javafx\scene\control\TextInputControl.java line 359*

```java
    private TextProperty text = new TextProperty();
    public final String getText() { return text.get(); }
    public final void setText(String value) { text.set(value); }
    public final StringProperty textProperty() { return text; }
```

This proves `.getText()` returns the value from `TextProperty`.

*Disclamation*

I know little about javafx, but I'm familiar with Windows Forms and WPF. I think javafx follow similiar philosophy.

Comment: I would still like to thank you for the quick and well put answer!